# Pausing item creation until a change is approved

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I want to use an approval workflow to accept or reject additions to my sharepoint site. The caveat is that I don't want any changes that are pending approval to appear. Only changes that have been submitted and approved should be visible to others who open the page.

Is a workflow the best way to go about this? If it is, what do I need to change from the OTB Approval solution to have only approved changes be visible? Or is this a code-only problem that I need to dig deeper to solve?

I'm currently testing this with a Calendar web part, but the solution to this could potentially apply to any other type added to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, there are two requirements:

1. Being able to change your site and have the updates only visible to a select few
2. (optional) A workflow to handle the process.

So the first requirement could be handled by the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure.  Take a look at the interwebs and see if that would work for you.  You could also just require approval for items added to the library where your pages are stored but that doesn't seem as straightforward.

I mentioned your second requirement being optional because it might be overkill depending on your situation.  You would want to require approval on the library, then attach a workflow to the library.  But if you're in constant contact with the approver(s) otherwise, it might be just as easy to say "he dude, check out the 'About Us' page, if you like it, click the approve button in the toolbar".

Hope that helps.  There's probably a bunch of different ways to go about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Popdan. You're definitely right about (2) being optional. I was only looking into workflows because I thought that's what I needed. Regarding (1), your solution about for pages that are added sounds spot on. Is there a way to do that for specific web parts or individual changes? I'm gonna take a look at that Publishing Infrastructure and see what I find. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't been in front of SharePoint for a little while so I'm going mostly off memory... web parts are treated differently than pages, documents, list items, etc.  You can save a page in a library or an item in a list, both of which can be set to require approval.  But web parts are saved in the web part gallery, and that's only when you take the extra step to do so.  If you add a web part to a page and make some config changes, there's no place I know of to see that new web part other than the page, so that's where you end up attaching to the library it's stored in for changes...

Comment: Gotcha. I think I have an idea of where I need to focus my attention now. Appreciate your help.